# Is the subjunctive mood something that can exist without manifesting a change in the verb?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood, conjugation, mood

Is the subjunctive mood a condition which might not be expressed through any change in the verb, or is it a description that only applies when the verb changes?

For example: "Mary ought be here soon."  Subjunctive mood.
But how about:  "Mary ought to be here soon."  Subjunctive?

Comment: Those are both infinitives, not subjunctives. Why would the subjunctive only be a thing if the verb changes? Any category of verbal inflection may or may not have a surface manifestation in a given paradigm. “I set it up [yesterday]” is no less a past form of “I set it up [every day]” because the verb is the same in both cases; and the imperative is _mandatorily_ identical to both the infinitive and the subjunctive in all verbs.

Comment: I suppose this is new information, but I'll put it here.  The reason I want to know this is that I am a debate coach, and the current Public Forum topic is "The right to be forgotten from the internet ought to be a civil right."  Can you, @JanusBahsJacquet tell me if that sentence is subjunctive?  I could explain the whole argument I want to run but it's complicated.

Comment: No, it’s not a subjunctive. It’s an infinitive complement _to be_ of the auxiliary verb _ought_. You could argue that _ought to [infinitive]_ is semantically similar to a jussive-hortative subjunctive in function; but it is not one in form, regardless of whether you delete the _to_. It’s the same as in _can go_ or _will go_, where _go_ is also an infinitive, not a subjunctive.

Comment: If I were to argue similarity of function, how would I describe that function?  @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: I would just say they’re functionally similar, though formally distinct. But then I don’t know the first thing about debate teams, having never grown up in the States.

Comment: Additionally, do have any thoughts about how the use of the subjunctive or an equivalent relates to whether a sentence has a determinate truth value? @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: I'm trying to move this to chat, but I don't know how.  Please define the function.

Answer (score 1):

"Mary ought be here soon."

There is no subjunctive form in that sentence.

Comment: Not only that, it's [ungrammatical](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+ought+be%2C+He+ought+to+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20ought%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0) in standard English.

Comment: @PeterShor I know the Ngrams don't show it, but I have heard people say things like 'he ought tell him'. But I don't think it is the subjunctive - if there is such a thing!

Comment: WS2: People speaking various dialects of English say all sort of things. Many of them are ungrammatical in standard English.

Comment: The current PF topic in debate is:
"The right to be forgotten on the internet ought to be a civil right."  Is that subjunctive?  2WS2 and @PeterShor Would it be subjunctive if it said "ought be" instead?  Does it make a difference?  Apparently, btw, that "ought be" is an American thing mostly, not so much in Britain.

Comment: @EricStraussThere is no subjunctive in your sentence. *ought* is a fringe member of the modal verbs. Some of these are used as in alternative constructions to those containing subjunctive forms, but they are not themselves subjunctive forms.

Comment: @tunny But isn't subjunctive a mood?  This brings me back to my original question.  Janus says: "Any category of verbal inflection may or may not have a surface manifestation in a given paradigm."  Is this an example of such an occurence?

Comment: @Eric: the subjunctive (or at least the descendants of the original Indo-European subjunctive) is used for so many different things in various languages, it's not clear to me they can be classified as one semantic mood. *"I demand that he be brought to me"* is an example of an English subjunctive. Why isn't it an imperative, like *"Bring him to me"*? And if you say the subjunctive represents [a mood of verbs expressing what is imagined or wished or possible](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/express#express), as ODO does, why isn't *"it may rain tomorrow"* subjunctive?